# How to remove punctuation around a string

Tags: c++

I want to remove the punctuation around a string such that the string:

```
 !dont't?.
```

will becomes:

```
 don't
```

I have only seem to be able to remove all punctuation in a string with:

```
int len = str.size();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
    if (ispunct(str[i])){
        str.erase(i--, 1);
        len = str.size();
    }
}
```

Do you guys know a simple way to get rid of all punctuation from the front and back only?

Comment: how will you identify whether your word is going to start or its going to end. Small hint..

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use `boost::trim_if` ([see it work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e59d585d569f6ad1)):

```
boost::trim_if(str, boost::is_punct());
```

Answer (score 4):

You could erase from the front until you see something that isn't punctuation, then do the same from the back.

```
for (auto it = std::begin(s); std::ispunct(*it);) {
    it = s.erase(it);
}
for (auto it = std::prev(std::end(s)); std::ispunct(*it); --it) {
    it = s.erase(it);
}
```

You should be sure to handle edge cases like empty strings as well.

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f8171f487bee075)